# Windows Phone app crashes only if downloaded from the store

Tags: crash, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, marketplace

I have a really strange problem, I developed a windows phone app that works perfectly if installed from visual studio... I uploaded on the store as beta, installed from the store, but the app crashes always on splashscreen!

Thanks

Comment: Why a downvote? I cannot say nothing more, I have really no Idea what to say!!!

Comment: What's the app? What does it do? It's probably a capabilities or memory issue.

Comment: the app load news from rss, gallery from facebook, tweets and events from google calendar. but on start doesn't load anything only the mainpage that doesn't appear because crash on splashscreen.

After I installed from visual studio I can use the app without problems also standalone loading from menu.

about capabilities there are selected all the standard ones except gamerservices

i tried to install the build xap with windows phone application deployment tool and it works with no problems!

Comment: The XAP file you submit to the store is recompiled before being made available publically. Something in that process has obviously gone wrong. If you can't share the beta link check your stack traces in the dev centre and trying contacting marketplace support.

Comment: I'll try to contact support, is there a chance to contact you private in stackoverflow? i can send you the link but i first need your email to add you to beta testing :)
THANKS!

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't support private messaging but if you look at my profile you see a link to a private domain. I'm sure you can work out how to send me an email from that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're application uses a periodic Background Agent and you are testing it with the `LaunchForTest` method you should make sure that you are not calling this in your release build of the code.
Protect it with appropriate conditional compile time checks:

```
#if DEBUG
ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
#endif
```

Note that `DEBUG` is defined by default in the "Debug" configuration and not in the "Release" one for situations such as this.

It would be nice if the automated tests done by the marketplace/store detected this but currently they don't. Maybe one day...

Comment: Does anyone know if you can use ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest in Release configuration when testing your own code.  I.E. test release build that is not in the store?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your app takes longer than 4 seconds to become usable. During debugging that requirement is disabled, but when it's on the store your app needs to be snappy.

Comment: Thanks I'll take care of this suggest too, till now I tried:
- Edit capabilities: no luck
- Now I'm trying to delete all debug and ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest references
- Later I will check as suggested from microsoft support if the app write to the install directory
- At the end I will try also your suggest, the app starts really fast because it's just a menu, but now loads some datas from twitte after at starts...maybe could be that
Thanks

Comment: Yes, definitely don't call ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest in release code - this WILL crash the app too (been there/done that! :D)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much guys, yes the problem was the ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest, now I commented all code this way:

```
//#define DEBUG_AGENT

 //#if(DEBUG_AGENT)
        //ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
        //#endif
```

Do you think that i can uncomment the second part, this way:

```
//#define DEBUG_AGENT

 #if(DEBUG_AGENT)
        ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
        #endif
```

Do the app will work the same?

THANKS !!!