# WP8 app crashes after downloaded from store

Tags: windows-phone-8

Recently I created an app that uses background agent and live tiles in it. The problem is - the application works perfectly when I straight away deploy the XAP file to device(or emulator) but **when I download the same app from store, then the app exits** without even navigating to MainPage. 
Is this because of background agent or anything else, I don't know am totally confused in this. Can anybody please help with this?

Comment: You should have some crash reports in your dashboard at dev.windowsphone.com

Comment: @Pein Just now found the answer for the above. It's because of `LaunchForTest` method in background agent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're application uses a periodic Background Agent and you are testing it with the LaunchForTest method you should make sure that you are not calling this in your release build of the code.
Protect it with appropriate conditional compile time checks:

```
#if DEBUG
ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
#endif
```

Note that DEBUG is defined by default in the "Debug" configuration and not in the "Release" one for situations such as this.

Answered by Matt Lacey - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15339129/1392194